# How to output character array with spaces to a text file

Tags: c++

I am trying to write an array to a text file. However when I write it. anything beyond the first space gets omitted. I don't get anything beyond first space written to the file, like if I take "This is my assignment", I only get "This" written to my file. How can I modify this to get the whole input.

```
ofstream pFILE ("FILE.txt", ios::out);


char * data = new char[100]
cout<<"Enter data"<<endl;
cin>>data;

pFILE << data;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is input, not output.

```
cin >> data;
```

That stops storing into `data` at the first space, leaving the rest of your input remaining in the buffer.  Use `getline` instead.

```
cin.getline(data,100);
```

Even better is to use the standard string class, so you have to worry about neither size, nor cleanup.

```
std::string data;
std::getline(std::cin, data);
```

Answer (score 2):

Write this

```
std::cin.getline(data,100);
```

instead of

```
cin >> data;
```